# Showing progressbar until multiple async tasks are executed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

So I have a main Activity, where I have a button (ImageView), and a progressbar.
When I click that button I want to execute a series of AsyncTasks that download some data from a remote DB. I want to start the indeterminate progressbar when button is clicked and hide it when the last AsyncTask is done. Can I do that?

So I have

- MainActivity.class (that contains the button, progressbar and the
  code to call the asyncTasks)
- AsyncTask1.class (containing the code to get some data from DB)
- AsyncTask2.class (containing the code to get some data from DB)
- ...
- AsyncTaskn.class (containing the code to get some data from DB)

I cannot include all the asyncTask classes in the activity so I can refference the progressBar directly, So how can I access the progressbar from the last AsyncTask class in onPostExecute in order to hide it?

So my mainActivity looks like:

```
ImageView upd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_update);
    upd.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new AsyncTask1(getApplicationContext()).execute();
                new AsyncTask2(getApplicationContext()).execute();
                new AsyncTask3(getApplicationContext()).execute();
                new AsyncTask4(getApplicationContext()).execute();
                new AsyncTask5(getApplicationContext()).execute();
                new AsyncTask6(getApplicationContext()).execute();
                new AsyncTask7(getApplicationContext()).execute();
        }
    });
```

An example of a AsyncTask (they are all similar)

```
public class AsyncTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

    private Context mContext;
    InputStream is = null ;
    String result = "";

    public AsyncTask1 (Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void insSQLite(Integer iduzer, String tip_uzer, String nume, String parola, String numecomplet,
                          String email, String telefon, String idgrup, String den_grup, String idcoord, String nume_coord, String nume_coordfull ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = new myDbHelper(mContext).getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "";
        sql = "select iduzer from uzeri where trim(tip_uzer)='"+tip_uzer+"' and trim(numecomplet)='"+numecomplet+"'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    Log.e("... It exists ...", Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0)));
                    sql = "update uzeri set iduzer=" + iduzer + ",parola='" + parola + "',email='" + email + "',telefon='" + telefon + "', idgrup=" + idgrup + ", den_grup='" + den_grup + "', idcoord=" + idcoord + ", nume_coord='" + nume_coord + "', nume_coordfull='" + nume_coordfull + "'  where iduzer=" + Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0));
                    db.execSQL(sql);
            }
        }else{
                sql = "insert into uzeri (iduzer,tip_uzer,nume,parola,numecomplet,email,telefon, idgrup,den_grup,idcoord,nume_coord,nume_coordfull) values (" +
                        String.valueOf(iduzer) + ",'" + tip_uzer + "','" + nume + "','" + parola + "','" + numecomplet + "','" +
                        email + "','" + telefon + "'," + idgrup + ",'" + den_grup +"'," + idcoord + ",'" + nume_coord + "','" + nume_coordfull + "')";
                db.execSQL(sql);
        }
            db.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        postData("0");
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double v){
        if (!String.valueOf(result).trim().equals("null")) {
            try {
                JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
                    Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Integer iduzer = Jasonobject.getInt("iduser");
                    String tip_uzer = Jasonobject.getString("tip_uzer");
                    String nume = Jasonobject.getString("name");
                    String pass = Jasonobject.getString("pass");
                    String numecomplet = Jasonobject.getString("namecomplete");
                    String email = Jasonobject.getString("email");
                    String telefon = Jasonobject.getString("phone");
                    String idgrup = Jasonobject.getString("idgroup");
                    String den_grup = Jasonobject.getString("den_group");
                    String idcoord = Jasonobject.getString("idcoord");
                    String nume_coord = Jasonobject.getString("nume_coord");
                    String nume_coordfull = Jasonobject.getString("name_coordfull");
                    insSQLite(iduzer, tip_uzer, nume, pass, namecomplete, email, telefon, idgrup,den_grup,idcoord,nume_coord,nume_coordfull);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
        }else{
            Log.e("ASYNC UZ:","There are no users on the server");
        }
    }    

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
//        pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myserver.com/getusers.php");
        final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) mContext;
        String uzid = globalVariable.getUzer();

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uzeru", uzid));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            is =  httpEntity.getContent();
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while((line=br.readLine())!=null){ sb.append(line+"\n"); }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you really need 7 different tasks running at the some time? You may want to think about using a `Service`. Anyway, you can use an `interface` with a callback to your `Activity`. But, doing it this way, you won't know which will finish last. You could have a listener to continually check if each is still running but not sure that is the best way either.

Comment: hey put progress on all AsyncTask then it automatically show progress with all tasks

Comment: I am using web services for update. Each AsyncTask updates a certain table from the DB

Answer (score 0):

I will share you a idea. You could set up a variable like this:

```
int taskCount = 0;
```

Then,in every Asynctask's `onPostExecute` method, you could add the `taskCount` and test if `taskCount` is get the 7 value:

```
taskCount++; //WARN: here you maybe need java synchronized.
if(taskCount == 7){
    //all task is done , just do your work. 
    //hide the progressbar.
}
```

Wish this idea could give you some tips.

Comment: How do I refference the progressbar on the activity, from the AsyncTask in order to hide it? The variable taskCount should be a global one then...??!?!?

Comment: 1.Make the progressbar global. 2 yes.

Comment: I must rephrase my question because it is not going the way I intended. Please check the edit above...

Comment: make the asynctask class in your mainActivity and after you have done all the thing in `onPostExecute` method, you could check whether the `taskCount` is equal to `7`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but, I would hate to put ALL my asyncTask classes inside my MainActivity class, because I will have there at least 7 AsyncTasks, most likely there will be around 15, so adding 15 AsyncTasks inside one class it would be awfull. I want to avoid that, so that is why I asked this question. Is there any way to access the progressbar of mainActivity from external class (AsyncTask) without having to add all the asyncTasks into the main class?

Comment: Another reason to not put them inside MainActivity is that I also have a service that periodically performs updates if necessary and I would like to have the service call the same 15 asyncTasks. Of course I could keep the external classes and copy them into mainActivity too, but that does not look like a healthy approach...